How to prevent auto-scrolling of v-select
I couldn't find a way to prevent scrolling of v-select in Vuetify 3. It was optional in Vuetify 2 with :menu-props="auto". I have a demo here. Code is like below:
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-select v-model="selected" :items="items" />
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { reactive } from 'vue'
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  const selected = ref('item10')
  const items = reactive([
    'item1',
    'item2',
    'item3',
    'item4',
    'item5',
    'item6',
    'item7',
    'item8',
    'item9',
    'item10',
    'item11',
  ])
</script>


How can I prevent auto-scrolling after I expand component?
I tried programatically prevent scrolling with using ref. ChatGPT suggested using this.$refs.selector.$refs.menu.scrollTop = 0 but selector does not have any $refs.

What do you mean by scrolling? Going to the 10th item? You would like it to stay on the first one? For once, I guess that GPT's answer is not too bad but yes, you could use something like $refs.menu.scrollTop = 0. Adapt it to the DOM you have there.

@kissu yes I tried that but menu instantly closes as soon as I open inspector tool from dev tools.

You could try to look for a prop to let it open otherwise check the classes applied to the element you're trying to inspect. I get how annoying it can be...

The hideSelected prop removes selected items from the list, and looking at the code, it seems to be the only way to programmatically disable the scroll effect.
